# how to catch all GenericMotionEvent when a DialogFragment is shown?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, joypad

I need to show a preference dialog that wait for Joypad keypress.

I know that `DialogFragment` has its own Window then has its own `onKeyListener`.

I can easily catch Joypad press by setting a listener like that.

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends PreferenceDialogFragmentCompat  {

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
        super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

        builder.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                // do stuff with intercepted key press

                return true;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But, I have trouble catching `GenericMotionEvents`. In order to intercept them, I've overridden `onGenericMotionEvents` in the Activity class and eventually forward the Event by calling a method on `MyDialogFragment` class.

It works 100% correctly when `MyDialogFragment` is not shown as when an analog trigger/direction stick is moved, I can get an event.

The weird part is that IF `MyDialogFragment` is shown, then I can get only analog direction stick events BUT NOT left/right analog triggers events.

Does someone know why and how to fix this behaviuor?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue some time ago. You can use `onGenericMotionEvent` of `Dialog` or even some of the `View`s. It has some [limitations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onGenericMotionEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) though and works not as expected sometimes. It does work as intended though - it is just that sometimes all the generic motion events are being intercepted by something else and they aren't propagated any further anywhere - in this situation, you won't receive the callback trigger.

That is what was happening in my case and even overriding the callback method in `Dialog`(I haven't tried `View` though) failed to give me the needed result. What I did is a bit of a kludgy trick, but it did the job. I created my activity's UI as a child of one parent `FrameLayout` and my dialog UI was the topmost element in this `FrameLayout`. This trick allowed me to use the activity's native `onGenericMotionEvent` callback. It added some navigation handling overhead and was generally possible because of allowing UI design(without dialog shadow etc) but yeah...

Maybe some of these approaches will help you.